# Coroutine Exception throws KotlinNullPointerException

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, mvvm, kotlin-coroutines

I'm requesting an object from Firebase, but before requesting it, I check if there is an active internet connection in order to get the results, I call my repo this way

### ViewModel

```
class ArtistsViewModel(private val repo: IArtists):ViewModel() {


    val fetchArtistsList = liveData(Dispatchers.IO){
        emit(Resource.Loading())
        try {
            val artistList = repo.getArtists()
            emit(artistList)

        }catch (e:Exception){
            Crashlytics.logException(e.cause)
            emit(Resource.Failure(e.cause!!))
        }

    }
}
```

### Repo

```
class ArtistsRepoImpl : ArtistsRepo {

    override suspend fun getArtists(): Resource<MutableList<Artist>> {
        val artistList = mutableListOf<Artist>()
        if(InternetCheck.isInternetWorking()){
            val resultList = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                .collection("artists")
                .get().await()
        }else{
            throw Exception("No internet connection")
        }

        return Resource.Success(artistList)
    }
}
```

Now, when there is no internet connection, an Exception should return to my viewmodel, here is where I use `throw Exception("No internet connection")` to propagate the exception but now at my ViewModel I get this message

> kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException     at
>   com.presentation.viewmodel.ArtistsViewModel$fetchArtistList$1.invokeSuspend(ArtistsViewModel.kt:22)
>     at
>   kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
>     at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(Dispatched.kt:241)     at
>   kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:594)
>     at
>   kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.access$runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:60)
>     at
>   kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:740)

The error log points to this line in my ViewModel

```
emit(Resource.Failure(e.cause!!))
```

What I dont understand is why its giving a `KotlinNullPointerException`  when it should handle the **Exception** message that I throw.

Also, is there a better way to catch any exception instead of **Exception** at my ViewModel ?

Comment: You need to get the message from the exception. Not the cause. The cause is another exception. When you throw something like Exception(IOException("Network Failure"))

Comment: yes, but I get the message from the ui doing this it.throwable.message

Comment: What message? And what is 'it' here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

KotlinNullPointerException can happen when you force an unsafe type conversation of a nullable type with the `!!` operator.  That means the object `e.cause` is actually null.  You should check it for null instead of blindly assuming it's non-null.

What you should do instead is [check the type](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html) of the exception class to see if it corresponds to the exception you would expect in the case of a lack of network connectivity.

Comment: Thanks Doug, in the case the exception is not of the type Exception, can I get the type of that exception and throw it ? Lets say my repo code can throw more than 1 exception, how can I handle them all in one exception?

Comment: Sure, you can re-throw a caught exception.